# Weird paste string appends to my text when pasting from my clipboard manager (Ditto) to MobaXTerm

Tags: windows, clipboard, mobaxterm, ditto

When selecting some entries from my Ditto clipboard manager with the keybind (Ctrl+q)[image]

And then pasting it on the MobaXTerm program, a weird string appends to the text and then I'll have to delete it, which is pretty anoying. 
[image]

As you see the string should look like this: *csi-node-driver-hx77z* but instead it looks like this: *^[[200~csi-node-driver-hx77z~*

Comment: This is due to bracketed paste being enabled: https://superuser.com/questions/1532688/pasting-required-text-into-terminal-emulator-results-in-200required-text

Answer (score 1):

```bash
vim ~/.inputrc

# disable 
set enable-bracketed-paste 0

# wq # save
```

exit the terminal then login again, just paste some words in terminal, nothing dirty my terminal again...

it works for me!!!

Comment: This works, but having to do it manually on each device accessed by ssh is a bit of a pain. Not to say that there are some terminals where I won't be able to create or edit this file (for security reasons).
Ty anyway man

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was occurring with me today. I discovered that the error occurs only the first time I paste the memory content using the mouse right click.

Workaround:

1. Mouse right click => it pastes wrongly  `^[[200~...`
2. Press CTRL+C to ignore the command. The system goes to the next line
3. Mouse right click again and it should paste the content correctly now